# AspNet Core API can't get two GETs on same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a controller like this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AssociationKeysController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public override IActionResult Get(Guid id)
    {
        ....
    }

    [Route(nameof(ClaimedInfo))]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ClaimedInfo(Guid id)
    {
        ....
    }
```

If I get the route system correctly, I expect that the first action could be accessed with `/api/associationkeys/<<id>>` and the second using `/api/associationkeys/claimedinfo?id=<<id>>`, but both urls are being executed by the `Get` method.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your routing is not correct, you should use this :

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Or this one in WebApiStartup file

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "YourApiName",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
```

Comment: With your answer the first action would have to be called with `/api/associationkeys/get/<<id>>` instead of `/api/associationkeys/<<id>>`. And then alll other actions I have that are named DELETE, PUT, etc will have to be called by their name also. If there's no way to do that, I wonder what's the point of having the Http verbs?